# Where do I pay tax if I am a digital nomad with residency of more than one country?

Tags: income-tax, international

I am citizen of country A. I moved to country B few years ago where I opened a virtual bank account with a organization registered in country C while using country B as my residence.

Now I don't live in country B anymore but still has the bank account. I travel in different countries and mostly pay using card/ATM withdrawals with that bank account. I receive income as freelancer and my clients are all over the world (co-incidentally not even one in either of the countries so far).

Note: None of these countries require you to pay income taxes on incoming earned abroad.

So which country I am obliged to pay income tax?

Comment: Usually it is the country in which you are physically located while working. For example if you were to visit the US (with the appropriate visa) and do work here, you would be liable for US Federal/State income tax, even as a non-resident (in general, there are tax treaties that can alter this). What country of residence does your passport say (I assume Country A)? This is highly dependent on the specific country, so you can't just say "A/B/C".

Comment: @RonBeyer My passport for country A. I mostly travel as tourist and spent < 1 month in a country so far.

Comment: If A is either the USA or Eritrea you would have pay income tax in A. These are the only two countries that have taxation based on on citizenship.

Comment: @Hilmar No fortunately :)

Comment: Consider whether you are committing immigration fraud by working in these countries - do you really have work visas in all of them?

Comment: You might get more precise answers if you specified which country A, B and C are. Is there a reason you are aliasing them?

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on the specifics of the tax treaties between the countries involved. If you haven't established a tax residence in any country since leaving country B, you are likely still going to be considered tax resident there.

I would start by contacting an accountant in your current physical location who deals with expats from country B and see what they say.

Comment: I will check. Thanks. I hope it's not country B. They have pretty high tax rates. Beside I prefer to pay tax and contribute to economy of my home country A.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to generalize a question like that because it entirely depends on the tax laws of the countries in question. It's possible that you only need to pay taxes to country C while it's also possible that you need to pay taxes in countries A, B and C.
In most cases there are tax treaties between the countries that simplify things, but that doesn't go for all the countries and all situations.